# Spring data Redis HGETALL operation

Tags: spring, redis, spring-data, jedis

I am using `Redis` as data store for my spring web application and using `Spring Data-Redis` as my client to interact with `Redis`.

I am using `HashMap` to store one my objects having multiple fields. I am able to put all the fields into `Redis` at once using `DefaultRedisMap.putAll()` method, but I am not able to get the whole object at once instead using `BoundHashOperations` to get each field using `get()` method.

I am wondering is there any way I can do that just like `HGETALL` operation supported in `Redis`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

DefaultRedisMap.entrySet() or BoundHashOperations.entries() should give you all the keys and values at once.

Answer (score 5):

you can use HashOps::entries() to get all the entries (key and value) at once.