# how to get both keys and values when using redis's 'keys' command

Tags: redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I want to get both keys and values . Now I'm doing it like this:

```
Set<String> keys = redisTemplate.keys("Tom*");
if (keys != null) {

   //get them one by one
   for (String key : keys) {
      String value = redisTemplate.opsForValue().get(key);
   }
}
```

first, I have to get all the keys which starts with "abc". second, I get values one by one.

Can I get both keys and values at one time?

**UPDATE**:

Thank soveran.
I have some properties associated to each user:

```
1)Tom.loginTimes=3  
2)Tom.tradeMoneyCount=100
```

Before I define two separated keys:   Tom.loginTimes and Tom.tradeMoneyCount. 
Now I think I should use hmset:

```
10.75.201.3:63790> hmset Tom loginTimes 3 tradeMoneyCount 100
OK
10.75.201.3:63790> hgetall Tom
1) "loginTimes"
2) "3"
3) "tradeMoneyCount"
4) "100"
```

Thanks.

Comment: You can't, but also make sure you read the "Warning" note in the documentation for the `KEYS` command: http://redis.io/commands/keys

Comment: Can you describe your use case? Maybe we can come up with a different solution.

Comment: we want something like: select * from table_name where column_name like 'abc*'. Now I'm wondering how can I do this in redis.

Comment: Thank soveran.  I have some properties associated to each user:  1) Tom.loginTimes=3  2)Tom.tradeMoneyCount=100. Before I define two separate keys:   Tom.loginTimes and Tom.tradeMoneyCount. Now I think I should use hmset: hmset Tom loginTimes 3 tradeMoneyCount 100. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[hashes](http://redis.io/topics/data-types-intro#hashes) is the right way to do it.

As for the [keys](http://redis.io/commands/keys) command, it was added to redis for debug purposes and never meant to be used in production. Here is a warning from [redis docs for `keys` command](http://redis.io/commands/keys):

> **Warning:** consider [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) as a command that should only be used in production environments with extreme care. It may ruin
>   performance when it is executed against large databases. This command
>   is intended for debugging and special operations, such as changing
>   your keyspace layout. Don't use [KEYS](http://redis.io/commands/keys) in your regular
>   application code. If you're looking for a way to find keys in a subset
>   of your keyspace, consider using [SCAN](http://redis.io/commands/scan) or [sets](http://redis.io/topics/data-types#sets).

Comment: but use spring-data's RedisTemplate to 'hgetall' is a litte weird:Map<Object, Object> entries = redisTemplate.boundHashOps(name).entries();     see:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230205/spring-data-redis-hgetall-operation

Answer (score 1):

You can use below kind of code to get all the keys at the same time, and it returns a set of keys. I am using the Spring Redis API:

```
public StringBuffer getAllKeys() {

       System.out.println("get all keys");

       StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

       Set<byte[]> keys = redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory().getConnection().keys("*".getBytes());

       Iterator<byte[]> it = keys.iterator();

       while(it.hasNext()){

           byte[] data = (byte[])it.next();
           sb.append(new String(data, 0, data.length));
              }

       return sb;
    }
```